# Laravel job board app: Best method to check if user has applied for a job

Tags: php, laravel

So I’m developing an jobs board app using Laravel and wanted to know the most efficient method to check if a user has applied for a job?

I’m asking because my current idea (see below) of doing it seems like it may not be the best method and I wanted to cross check with you guys here.

*My method*

Involves creating a `many-to-many` relationship from a user and a job on a `job_users` or `user_jobs` table, then once they load a particular job, checking on the server referencing the relationship table to see if they have already applied.

Is that the most efficient way? Because it involves a call to the database every time and if the user has applied for many jobs, that seems highly inefficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that the query you described could become inefficient. There are different strategies you can use to solve this. First off, you can obey the general rule that "premature optimization is the root of all evil" and not solve it until it actually has an observable negative affect in production. Second, you could have a field like `status` or `has_posted_job` on the `users` table that is updated by the application when the user posts a job. The drawbacks of this is the additional application complexity, and the storage of the additional column, but it may be worth it. That goes back to "root of all evil" though -- it'd be best to first get production, real-world metrics on the inefficiency in order to know the best way to optimize it.

Comment: I believe I didn't explain clearly enough, the application will have users with two roles `candidates` and `employers` (with their own tables) whereby employers post jobs and candidates apply for them. Now I want to check if a candidate has applied already for a job an employer has posted. Are you suggesting to add this `had_posted_job` to an employer's table?

Comment: Oh okay, I would still recommend not optimizing this yet, especially since this is already an efficient query really. The `candidate_employer` table will have foreign keys I assume, which MySQL automatically indexes, so those look ups will be very quick.